# Removing unused information from JSON

Tags: java, json, string

I am currently working with a SonicWall router. I am trying to get some information from it for a project. I am connecting to it via SSH and I have selected JSON as an output format to get all the information. The problem I have is the following. For simple commands the returned is pretty straightforward to parse but for more complex ones the returned JSON might not valid.

**Here is a short example (these are NAT policies):**

```
    {
    "success": true,
    "cli": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "nat-policy" }, { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" }, { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" }, { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SNMP" } ] },
        { "submode": [
            { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "0" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SNMP" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
            { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
        ] },
      { "command": [ { "token": "end" } ] }
    ] }
```

So as far as I can understand the return JSON contains a field "success" and a field "cli" which contains a field "command" that is a list of tokens and a field "submode" that is a list of commands that each hold a list of tokens.

I would like to remove the field "command" along with the list of token it holds so the result would be something like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"cli": [
    { "submode": [
        { "command": [ { "token": "id" }, { "token": "0" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "inbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "outbound" }, { "token": "X1" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "source" }, { "token": "any" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-source" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "destination" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "WAN Primary IP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-destination" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "service" }, { "token": "name" }, { "token": "SNMP" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "translated-service" }, { "token": "original" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "enable" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "comment" }, { "token": "Management NAT Policy" } ] },
        { "command": [ { "token": "exit" } ] }
    ] }
] }
```

In essence I would only like to keep the "submode" field with the command list.

I am doing this in Java and cannot find a way to substring the returned JSON to get the expected result. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: What JSON-processing library are you using? Using substring() is not a robust choice

Comment: I recommend you to create a Java Class to Parse that Json (Using Gson for example) and then working with this parsed Object is easier.

Comment: I don't have too much experience working with JSON. I am using the default parser of Jackson. I have created the appropriate class to handle it, but I cannot do it properly because the cli list contains elements of two different types and I think that Jackson cannot parse it.

Comment: So you have Object to represent that JSON components? Maybe you can create a common Class called CliElement and, both command and submode extend of it class.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [java jsonp](https://jsonp.java.net/):

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(myJsonStream);
JsonObject obj = reader.readObject();

JsonBuilderFactory factory = Json.createBuilderFactory(null);
JsonObject myJson = factory.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("success", obj.get("success"))
    .add("cli", factory.createArrayBuilder()
        .add(factory.createObjectBuilder()
            .add("submode", obj.getJsonArray("cli").getJsonObject(1).get("submode")))).build();


FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("my_new_json_path");
JsonWriter wr = Json.createWriter(fs);
wr.writeObject(myJson);
wr.close();
```

Is bind to your json structure but it works!

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar but without using the jsonp?

Comment: For example using Jackson?

Comment: My solution is with jsonp (jsr-353) and is not bind to an implementation, you can use glassfish or jackson impl

Comment: I tried to implement what you suggested as it is actually the easiest way I have found already, but when I try to run it i get the following exception:

Exception in thread "main" javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
 at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:97)
 at javax.json.Json.createReader(Json.java:220)

Comment: My mistake, I had forgot to include the RI as well. Anyways it worked brilliantly except one thing. I am managing to get only one JSON and not the whole bunch. As mentioned above, this is only an example of the representation of a nat policy. The router's response my include many. How could it be able to get the others as well?